# Spring Data MongoDB: combine object's two fields for a Criteria query

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, criteria, mongorepository

I'm trying to create a Criteria List from `.mongodb.core.query.Criteria` in spring app with mongoRepository and I've stucked with an issue where I have Customer object with two fields - "name" and "surname" - and I need to create "or" query looking somehow like this:

```
  criteria.add(new Criteria().orOperator(
      Criteria.where("customerName").regex(stringData),
      Criteria.where("customerSurname").regex(stringData),
      Criteria.where("customerData.name","customerData.surname").regex(stringData)
  ))
```

So if the stringData was "Alex" i would get objects
`[{name: "Alex", surname: "Ich"}, {name: "Agatha", surname: "Alex"}]`, but if I would type "Agatha Alex" i would get object `[{name: "Agatha", surname: "Alex"}]` as a result. Could someone push me into the right direction how to this out?